# How did Jack get his memories?

Tags: oblivion

How could the original Jack's memories be transmitted to/surface in a clone?

Instincts, OK, character traits for sure, but memories?

It obviously did not come from the Tet, which had the convenient "memory wipe for security purposes" cover.

Comment: We're never told exactly what cloning technology is used. I suspect it's not actual real-world cloning, but more like a perfect copy, which also copies the "mind". Obviously real-world cloning doesn't work like that.

Comment: @AndresF. Thanks for your perspective.  I actually had heard something a bit similar to what you are suggesting in a comment to [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/47415/3797) by JohnO.  I've asked them to consider upgrading the comment to an answer, and I'll make the same request of you.  Would you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would seem that the Jack (and Vika) clones aren't what we would call clones today. They were not grown from the same DNA template in the normal way. The fact that all the clones are of the same age and appearance indicate that they are more likely **exact copies** of the original Jack and Vika. Being exact copies means that they retain the original's memories, although they are suppressed by some form of brain washing done by the Tet.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that makes sense.  The closest term we (and Beech) had to that concept was 'clone'.  It makes sense he'd think of, and refer to them as, clones.

Answer (score 2):

The memories came from the original Jack, when the clone of Jack saw the female(cannot remember her name) it triggered the memories that were suppressed in his mind.

Comment: So, they're gholas rather than clones?

Comment: They are clones, but memories were suppressed and not wiped.

Comment: Jack was already having dreams of Julia before he saw her at the site of the crashed pod (with the hyper-sleeping astronauts).  In fact, the movie *starts* with a dream of seeing Julia in New York.