# Why so many workers, so close to job completion?

Tags: clones, oblivion

Why was the Tet so full of clones so close to victory? You'd think at that stage it'd be scaling down production.

The number of clones in the Tet must have amounted to thousands, and I'd guess it took quite a lot of resources to grow them.

Comment: I don't have any direct support for this, but my assumption would be there's a time investment in growing the clones, which means having extras is faster than growing extras.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. There is no reason to assume the Tet was near completing its project.  If the Tet were a self-replicating machine, a basic strategy would be to mine energy and other resources from Earth to make as many Tets as possible.  Fifty years isn't nearly enough time to sift all the deuterium out of Earth's oceans, or to strip mine the planet for metals, fissile materials and whatever else an agent of a Kardashev type 1 civilization might find useful.
2. The extra Jacks and Vikas might be there for contingencies.  The scavs were still mounting significant resistance.  The Tet could not be completely sure that a large number of clones would not be needed suddenly, so it would be prudent to have them on hand.
3. We don't know how many Jacks and Vikas are deployed on Earth.  A large number of replacement clones might need to be baking at any given time to deal with voluntary "retirements" and involuntary ones due to scav attacks.

Comment: re. point 1.  I had been fooled into thinking it had by the statements of Jack/Vicka (which might be based on complete lies) and partly by some statements that Beacham had made.  I have now come to almost the opposite conclusion.  Beacham was mistaken and Jack/Vicka were being manipulated into thinking that.  Interesting points 2./3., I had not considered.

Answer (score 6):

Since the Tet is an automated system that has been using the Earth's own resources to power itself (and as a source of genetic material to make soldier clones) and since the "scavs" are proving annoyingly persistent as a guerilla force, I think we can reasonably assume that [Sally](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Sally_%28Oblivion%29) would consider creating and storing clones on case of a resurgence of resistance to be worthwhile activity.

Heck, It's not like it costs them anything.

[image]

On the other hand it might just be one of the movie's **many, many** incomprehensible plot holes.

[image]

Comment: LOL.  +1 even for the graphic at bottom...  :)  See also my other (rather convoluted) [Berserker Theory](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/47415/3797).

Comment: I remain unconvinced that the people who made this film gave it that level of thought.

Comment: I fully agree with you.  This is one of 3 questions I asked earlier tonight.  They are the first 3 of **21** questions I intend to ask over the next few weeks (thought I'd better not inundate the site) each of which made me think.  What the huh..?

Comment: You can spam the site with Oblivion plotholes if you want, but the simple fact is that they're genuinely a result of poor writing and nothing else. http://www.filmmakingreview.com/plot-holes-in-oblivion/ 

You won't get any satisfaction here.

Comment: Maybe you have a point.  My time might be better spent by watching Elysium again for every time I feel like it. I thought that was a bloody great movie.  Even with the bits in Spanish that I couldn't understand..  ;)

Comment: Oh right!  That was *you* that raised the 'spamming' concept.  Gee do I feel foolish right now.  :P

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Tee hee. I have no objection dealing with Oblivion questions since I've watched it and read the shooting script but the reality is that it's tripe.

Comment: Out of curiosity.  Have you seen Elysium?  I saw it very soon after Oblivion, and felt that although it had a few 'What the huh?' moments, it was an altogether tighter and more logical story than Oblivion.

Comment: Yes. Elysium was a much better written film.